# jZebra - Getting started with raw commands

Tags: php, html, printing, zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I've been given the task of converting a web page with a barcode to a one click label print. I've got jZebra up and running, but I have no idea where to get started as far as understanding how to write commands for a printer.

I've Google'd just about everything I can think of regarding this.

Basically, I am trying to understand this code:

```
applet.append("^XA^CF,0,0,0^PR12^MD30^PW800^PON^CI13\n");
// Draws a line. applet.append("^FO0,147^GB800,4,4^FS\n");
applet.append("^FO0,401^GB800,4,4^FS\n");
applet.append("^FO0,736^GB800,4,4^FS\n");
applet.append("^FO35,92^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FD^FS\n");
applet.append("^FO615,156^AdN,0,0^FWN^FH^FD(123) 456-7890^FS\n");
```

Does anyone have links to or information regarding what these characters / commands like "^FO0,401^GB800,4,4^FS" mean or do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 9,000 hours in google:

> Many card printers (such as Zebra or Eltron manufactured printers)
>   need special RAW printer commands sent to them in order to perform
>   certain functions (such as magnetic strip encoding or barcode
>   printing). These RAW commands are usually sent as text in a
>   proprietary syntax. This RAW syntax **is specified by the printer manufacturer (usually in  the form of a developer's manual)**. Syntax
>   will vary drastically between printer manufacturers and printer
>   models.

Emphasis is mine. Probably want to google for a developer's manual.

Source: http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/OldSummaryDoNotUse

Comment: Thanks, one of my coworkers has worked with Zebra before and pointed out some specifics. Search zebra.com for "ZPL 2 Programming Guide" and the first result is some decent documentation. I think I'll be building a PHP class for this for future use.

Answer (score 4):

For zebra you this simple guide will help you.
On this Zebra commands

```
N
q609
Q203,26
B26,26,0,UA0,2,2,152,B,"777777"
A253,56,0,3,1,1,N,"JHON3:16"
A253,26,0,3,1,1,N,"JESUSLOVESYOU"
A253,86,0,3,1,1,N,"TEST TEST TEST"
A253,116,0,3,1,1,N,"ANOTHER TEST"
A253,146,0,3,1,1,N,"SOME LETTERS"
P1,1
```

on JZebra

```
     var applet = document.jzebra;
     if (applet != null) {
applet.append("N\n");
applet.append("q609\n");
applet.append("Q203,26\n");
 applet.append("B26,26,0,UA0,2,2,152,B,\"777777\"\n");
applet.append("A253,56,0,3,1,1,N,\"JHON3:16\"\n");
applet.append("A253,26,0,3,1,1,N,\"JESUSLOVESYOU\"\n");
applet.append("A253,86,0,3,1,1,N,\"TEST TEST TEST\"\n");
applet.append("A253,116,0,3,1,1,N,\"ANOTHER TEST\"\n");
applet.append("A253,146,0,3,1,1,N,\"SOME LETTERS\"\n");
applet.append("P1,1\n");}
```

Having clear this:

EPL is one command per line. A command starts out with a command identifier, typically a letter, followed by a comma-separated list of parameters specific to that command. You can look up each of these commands in the EPL2 programming documentation. Here’s an English-language version of the commands in the above example.

1. Sending an initial newline guarantees that any previous borked
     command is submitted.
2. [N] Clear the image buffer. This is an important step and
     generally should be the first command in any EPL document;
     who knows what state the previous job left the printer in.
3. [q] Set the label width to 609 dots (3 inch label x 203 dpi
     = 609 dots wide).
4. [Q] Set the label height to 203 dots (1 inch label) with a 26
     dot gap between the labels. (The printer will probably auto-
     sense, but this doesn't hurt.)
5. [B] Draw a UPC-A barcode with value "777777" at
     x = 26 dots (1/8 in), y = 26 dots (1/8 in) with a narrow bar
     width of 2 dots and make it 152 dots (3/4 in) high. (The
     origin of the label coordinate system is the top left corner
     of the label.)
6. [A] Draw the text "JESUSLOVESYOU" at
     x = 253 dots (3/4 in), y = 26 dots (1/8 in) in
     printer font "3", normal horizontal and vertical scaling,
     and no fancy white-on-black effect.

All tha A starting lines are similar.
10. [P] Print one copy of one label.