# Print barcode to Thermal Printer

Tags: java, printing, barcode, thermal-printer, code128

So I have a thermal printer (Kube II) and i'm trying to print a code128 barcode to it. The barcode I generate is too wide to fit on the receipt paper.

```
code128 = new Code128();
code128.setData(Encoded);
code128.setLineWidth(1);
code128.setHeight(25);
code128.generateBarcode();
```

I have tried shrinking it but the quality gets to the point where it cant be scanned any longer. I used Thumbnails to shrink it.

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("test.png"));
BufferedImage newImage = Thumbnails.of(originalImage).size(190, 25).asBufferedImage();
```

Does anyone have any idea as to how I can print the barcode to the printer and retain quality?

Comment: Have you had a look at <a>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282049/jzebra-getting-started-with-raw-commands</a>?

Comment: Are you trying to print a barcode that's just too long to fit?  Can you print it rotated 90º so it can be as long as it needs to be?